# Helping tendency of Stack Overflow is overflowing

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Whenever a user is making consecutive clicks on the help link which is provided adjacent to the comment box, some duplicate help boxes are appearing. I guess that this is being caused by duplicate ajax calls.

Please refer to the following screen shot:

[image]

The above mentioned behaviour of user is causing the following appearance too. Actually it is making the link's text as `help` even though the help box is displaying. Basically its text should have been like `hide help`.

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

Click on the help link which is closest to the comment box consecutively. Please ensure that you are clicking on that link first time, after the page got loaded. After retrieving the data from the server for the first time, they are storing it somewhere locally and using it for the next upcoming requests.

Tested in:  `IE 8,9,10` , `CHROME 30.0.1599.101` , `FIRE FOX 23.0.1` , `SAFARI 5.1.7`

OS : `WIN 7`, `WIN XP`

Reproducibility: `Behaviour 1 - Always` , `Behaviour 2 - Sometimes`

Comment: This is not a bug.? why downvote(s) ?

Comment: I can reproduce Behaviour 1 sometimes on Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue on Chrome 30.0.1599.66 and Firefox 24.0

Comment: @AmalMurali After seeing your comment, I just updated my FF to version 24 and tested it. Both behaviours are still reproducible.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Can you link me to one such question?

Comment: @AmalMurali This behaviour is not a question based. You can see it everywhere in SE websites. Just refresh your page and try it after every attempt of you. Make some quicker clicks over that link.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Oh yes, I can now reproduce the issue. Guess I wasn't quick when I tried this before.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce on iOS Chrome. A second box appears if we double/triple/click pretty fast before the box is loaded.

Comment: Reproduced Firefox 25, Windows 7

Comment: reproduced in chrome 31.0..1650.48 beta, fixing ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in rev `2013.11.11.1623` on meta and `2013.11.11.1145` on sites.

<strike>Fixed in rev `2013.11.11.1623` on meta and `2013.11.11.1145` on sites.</strike>

<strike>Fixed in rev `2013.11.11.1623` on meta and `2013.11.11.1145` on sites.</strike>

Comment: Great and Thanks on behalf of SE users. But I am very curious to know, why did you cross out that two lines.? I cant see any difference among those three lines.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I think it was a joke since your original post shows the help text three times.